# How do I find the moles of NaOH required to reach the equivalence point?

Tags: titration

> For each trial with the unknown acid, calculate the following:
>   a) Moles of $\ce{NaOH}$ required to reach the equivalence point.

I need help with part A. I have already solved and figured out the concentration of $\ce{NaOH}$ ($.125$M). I've been reading my notes and it says moles of acid will equal moles of base. I've tried solving for both using the volumes and molarity and using the $M_1V_1 = M_2V_2$
I think that's wrong and I'm not sure how else to solve it.

Do I even have the correct equation?
[image: Acid titration]

[image: Lab questions]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are titrating a monoprotic acid, the moles of acid and base should be the same at the equivalence point. To find the moles of base used to reach equivalence, you simply need to multiply the volume of base you added to reach equivalence by the molarity of the base (which you determined from your standardization runs). You also will then know the moles of acid, since they have to be the same at equivalence.